# Can Minolta Rokkor lenses be mounted on a Konica Autoreflex TC camera?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, minolta, konica

I have a Konica Autoreflex TC camera. I want to buy a new lens. I found someone who sells two lenses both from Minolta:

- 50mm f/1.7 Rokkor
- 50 mm f/1.4 Rokkor

Does anyone know if these fit my Konica autoreflex?

Comment: Your camera uses lens's with the Konica bayonet mount. Someone here can probably tell you if there is an adapter ( or if one is needed ) to go from a Minolta mount to a Konica mount, but You need to research the differences in how lens's mount to cameras so you have an understanding and a knowledge base for future lens options. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konica_AR-mount

Comment: Minolta Rokkor lenses will not work on a Konica camera body.  See [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: There may be some confusion, in this case, coming from the fact that Konica and Minolta are now merged into one company. That didn't happen until 2003 though - long after your camera was made. At the time your camera was made, there was no cooperation at all between Konica and Minolta.

Comment: @osullic Konica and Minolta are now gone... superceded by Sony.  Minolta AF lenses work on Sony A-mount bodies.

Comment: @xiota Konica and Minolta merged in 2003 to form Konica Minolta. In 2006, Konica Minolta sold (almost all of) its photo assets to Sony. Yes, I'm well aware that Sony continued camera/lens development using the A-mount that Minolta had originally introduced in 1985. Konica Minolta continues to operate, just not in the photographic industry.

Answer (score 3):

Your camera has Konica Bayonet II mount, which is also called Konica AR or K/AR mount.

Both those Minolta lenses use a Minolta MC mount and will not fit your camera.